# How to approach debugging IE11 firing oninput inappropriately on only my web page

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, dom-events, jquery-events

I have a textbox:

```
<input id="someTextbox" type="text" oninput="console.log('input')">
```

And in IE11, `"input"` will be printed when the textbox **has no input and gains or loses focus**. This does not happen in any other browsers, and I cannot reproduce it simply, so I assume some outside interference is causing this.

How would I ideally debug this?

I should mention that this textbox has the full definition

```
<input type="text"
    id="someTextbox" class="form-control"
    oninput="console.log('input')"
    placeholder="Type here" aria-label="Type here"
>
```

where `.form-control` is a Bootstrap CSS class.

Comment: Makes sense to me that something else is triggering it. Would try removing plugins $ other  external scripts as much as you can to see if it improves and see if you can isolate the culprit

Comment: @charlietfl You gave me the idea of just going around jQuery entirely, and it turns out `oninput` does the same thing. I wonder if JavaScript can even be the culprit at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the `placeholder`. It has nothing to do with the JavaScript, jQuery or Bootstrap you use. We can reproduce the issue with only the code below:

```html
<input id="someTextbox" type="text" oninput="console.log('input')" placeholder="Type here">
```

It seems a [known bug](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7138) in IE. As a workaround, you could use `onkeyup` instead of `oninput` in IE.